# Faking a GTK_RESPONSE_OK in a GTK dialog

Tags: gtk

I want to have a `gtk_file_chooser_dialog` that does not browse into a folder if it has a specific name. For this I hooked up my dialog with a callback when a `current-folder-changed` signal is emitted. In the callback function I successfully detect if the selected folder has the specific name. However, I can't figure out how to tell the dialog to close itself and return a specific response code (e.g. `GTK_RESPONSE_OK`).

I have unsuccessfully tried (among other things):

```
g_signal_emit_by_name(G_OBJECT(my_dialog), "response", GTK_RESPONSE_OK);
```

Has anyone a better idea ? I would appreciate any pointers into the right direction..

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying too hard. Just use:

```
gtk_dialog_response(GTK_DIALOG(my_dialog), GTK_RESPONSE_OK);
```

See the splendid [documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkDialog.html#gtk-dialog-response).